# Hibernate 3, fetch lazy : get field return null

Tags: java, spring, websphere-8, hibernate3

I have a issue with loading data about object mapped.

I have 2 entities classes.

The first :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5160452300417105888L;

    private Long idDocument;
    private Dossier dossier;
    private DocumentStatut documentStatut;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "Document_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Document_seq_gen", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_DOCUMENT")
    @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENT", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public Long getIdDocument() {
        return this.idDocument;
    }

    public void setIdDocument(final Long idDocument) {
        this.idDocument = idDocument;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOSSIER", nullable = false)
    public Dossier getDossier() {
        return this.dossier;
    }

    public void setDossier(final Dossier dossier) {
        this.dossier = dossier;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_STATUT", nullable = false)
    public DocumentStatut getDocumentStatut() {
        return this.documentStatut;
    }

    public void setDocumentStatut(final DocumentStatut documentStatut) {
        this.DocumentStatut = documentStatut;
    }

}
```

The second,

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT_STATUT")
public class DocumentStatut implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long idStatut;
    private String libStatut;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_STATUT", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public Long getIdStatut() {
        return this.idStatut;
    }

    public void setIdStatut(final Long idStatut) {
        this.idStatut = idStatut;
    }

    @Column(name = "LIB_STATUT", length = 30)
    public String getLibStatut() {
        return this.libStatut;
    }

    public void setLibStatut(final String libStatut) {
        this.libStatut = libStatut;
    }

}
```

I get Document data using org.hibernate.Criteria

For each Document instance, the field documentStatut has only his idStatut setted. I think it is normal because of lazy property.

But, when I call doument.getDocumentStatut(), I wish a sql select is executed for getting the others fields od DocumentStatut. But not, no query is launched and I have to "manually" execute a select query for getting a complete instance of DocumentStatut.

I use : 
 - hibernate 3.3.2.GA
 - Websphere 8.5
 - Spring 3.2.6.RELEASE
 - Java 7